# CSS @font-face isn't working with Mac font

Tags: css, font-face, truetype

I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for. I have an entirely static page, mostly made up of images. The font used to create the images is 'Handwriting-Dakota.ttf' found on any Mac OS X install. I have one dynamic element containing text which i want to give this font to.
I have the ttf font in the same directory as my css file.

```
@font-face{
 font-family: dakota;
 src: url('dakota.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

In an html file with the css file included. `<p style="font-family: dakota;">sometext</p>`

I can see the rule applied in chrome's inspector but it does not change the appearance. Is what I'm trying to do impossible or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this format

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url('fonts/myfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/myfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/myfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/myfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/myfont.svg#rsuregular') format('svg');
}
```

To further gain more knowledge about font-face syntax, read [Bulletproof @font-face Syntax](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/).

To get all versions of the font. google the "font converter", there will be plenty of font converter services in first page.

Comment: But where do I get all the versions of the font? I'm currently just trying to get it to work on chrome and from what i've read the ttf should work for that?

Comment: @Cobolt i have just updated my answer. You could try google for online  font converter to get all the versions of the font

Comment: Thank you, although I had to abandon the font I was using, using this format works very well as it generally just works. Font Squirrel said the ttf file was corrupt even though I tried versions from multiple sources. It seems there is something strage wrong with Handwriting Dakota.ttf

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the url is relative to the css file and not to the webroot.

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'dakota';
    src: url('../fonts/dakota.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

And you probably should add other types to make sure other browsers can use the font without problems.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'dakota';
    src: url('../fonts/dakota.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/dakota.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/dakota.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/dakota.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/dakota.svg#rsuregular') format('svg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Cobolt, you can try FontSquirrel. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator.

All you need is .otf or .ttf file. Then, FontSquirrel will make the .svg, .eot, .woff for you and create a css file.